# Recieving Sms using a broadcast receiver-xamarin

Tags: mono

My last question was not a great question.
so here my new one.

I want to write an app that has and activity which get some info(like a phone number) from the user and then It is destroyed and the app icon is also hidden from the user.but i want to continuously receive sms from that phone number and do some stuff.
until now i have learned that if i register my broadcast receiver in the manifest it can still receive even though my app is not running or hidden.
so here is my app which i'm using xamarin (mono android):
my simple activity (it is not complete yet):

my main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:orientation="vertical"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<EditText
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/txt_phone" />
<Button
    p1:text="OK"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/btn_ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity class:

```
namespace SmsBroadcastReceiver
{
[Activity (Label = "SmsBroadcastReceiver", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText txt_number = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txt_phone);
        Button btn_ok = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btn_ok);
        btn_ok.Click += delegate {
            //save the number in the sharedpreference and then...
            Toast.MakeText (Context, "Your App Will be Closed now", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        };
    }
}
}
```

now my broadcast receiver:

```
namespace SmsBroadcastReceiver
{
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (context, "sms rec", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        //get the sharedpreference and then do stuff
    }
}
}
```

and my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"         android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiver">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application android:label="SmsBroadcastReceiver">

</application>
  <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 </manifest>
```

I know that the using a toast in a BR is not ideal but i just want to see that it is working which is not,everytime i send and sms to my phone it doesn't show anything.
where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you created BroadcastReceiver in the wrong way.
You should create it entirely with xamarin attributes.
Mono for Android translates each `IntentFilterAttribute` into an `<intent-filter/>` element.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
...
}
```

therefore there is no need to write receiver tags manually in your AndroidManifest file.

You can also use attribute's named parameters for Priority, Categories, etc.

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = Int32.MaxValue)]
```

Comment: at laast someone.thank you so much i didn't know that.it works now.but how can i set my receiver priority this way?

Comment: thank you.so are you sure that by using this way my broadcast rec still react and get the sms after i closed the app?

Comment: what if i need to enable the broadcast receiver just when the OS is kitkat or newer?